# See when a directory was branched/tagged in SVN

Tags: svn, tags, tortoisesvn, subclipse

I'm currently working in the release process in a large project.

I simply need to know if a directory was modified in the trunk **after** it was tagged (so we need to make a new tag and release the new version).

I can use TortoiseSVN, CLI and Subclipse.

Tried with revision graph but found nothing useful... (or at least I was unable to use it properly)

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do it in two steps:

1. Get the version which was tagged. This can be done by checking the revision of the tag creation, from the commandline use `svn info` and check last changed rev.
2. Check for any changes in the source directory *after* that revision. From the commandline use `svn log -r 470:HEAD` where `470` is the revision number found in step 1.

Comment: Step 1 tells the revision number which created the tag. It says nothing about what was actually tagged. For example, if the trunk is at revision 469, I could do `svn cp -r123 ^/trunk ^/tags/foobar`. Now `svn info ^/tags/foobar` says "Last Changed Revision: 470". To find out later what revision I tagged, you'd have to do `svn log --stop-on-copy -v ^/tags/foobar`. I could also do `svn cp -r123 ^/trunk/onething ^/tags/foobar/onething; svn cp -r231 ^/trunk/anotherthing ^/tags/foobar/anotherthing`, of course, so now there is no single revision to which the tag corresponds.

Comment: @slowdog: You're right. I assumed that when tagging, HEAD is copied, not a specific (possibly older) version.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose from the root level directory, you could run

```
svn log path/to/directory --verbose
```

and should give you a list of all activity on that directory.  if you've got a revision number, you could also use that to narrow it down.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html

Comment: well, that's what revision numbers are good for, as exampled in the answer, but it was still the same subcommand.

Answer (score 1):

> I simply need to know if a directory was modified in the trunk after it was tagged (so we need to make a new tag and release the new version).

This might be of interest to you: Have you thought of using a continuous build system like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org). Every time someone does a commit, Jenkins will run a build.

So, how does this help you? Simple, you can use Jenkins to do tagging and marking a build that it was tagged in right in Jenkins. You can simply look at the project's webpage and see which builds were tagged. If there is a new check-in after the last tagged one, Jenkins will build it. And, you'll see it right in Jenkins. Even better, Jenkins can even automatically tag it for you.

This makes it easy for a developer to see the build, the output of the build, the changes, why those changes took place, and who made the change. If you have a defect tracking system, Jenkins can link to that, update issues that were built, and provide a link to the issue directly from Jenkins.

Jenkins can run and chart testing you do, run development software like [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) and Findbugs(http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/), and even mark builds that fail to live up to your impeccable standards. It'll email the developers after each bad build, so they can take care of the issue.

Jenkins is easy to setup, and simple to administer.

It's not exactly what you asked, but Jenkins may just do the trick.

Comment: +1 for the very interesting option. Since I don't control the build, and builds are done manually, I can't accept your answer. One day, if I will ever be managing a project, I'll surely consider such kind of release management

Comment: @djechelon: I didn't expect you'd accept my answer, but go ahead and download Jenkins and try it out. It's very light weight. All you need is a 1.6 Java runtime (BTW, you don't need to be a java shop to use Jenkins). It takes about 5 minutes to get it up and running. Depending upon how hard your app is to build, it'll take maybe another 20 minutes to an hour to setup your build. Then, see if you like it. If you do, show your developers and your release manager. If my employers knew how easy Jenkins is to use, they'd pay me a lot less money.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to know for sure if the current trunk matches a given tag is to run something like `svn diff --summarize ^/trunk/ ^/tags/foobar`. This is because tags in subersion are nothing more than a naming convention for directories. Any existing tag could represent a combination of multiple revisions, copied from anywhere in the repository.